# Third economic impact payment did not include new child

Tags: united-states, irs, covid-19, stimulus

Check was sent for $2800?

What are the steps to obtain additional $1400 for child?

I was perusing below to no avail:

[IRS 3rd payment here](https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/third-economic-impact-payment)

Comment: when was the child born? late 2020 or early 2021?

Answer (score 1):

From your link:

> The third round of Economic Impact Payments was authorized by the American Rescue Plan Act of 2021 as an advance payment of the tax year 2021 Recovery Rebate Credit.

It is an advance payment of a credit on your 2021 tax return, based on the information they had available from your most recent tax return (at the time they processed the payments).

If you got less than you actually qualify for you'll get the difference after you file your 2021 tax return.

Answer (score 1):

If your child was born in 2020, then they should have been included in your tax forms files in May 2021.  The [plus-up payment](https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/third-economic-impact-payment) rules would apply:

> Plus-Up Payments
>
> We are sending additional or plus-up payments to people who:
>
> - Already received a third Economic Impact Payment based on a 2019 tax return or information received from SSA, RRB or VA
> - May be eligible for a plus-up payment based on their 2020 tax return
>
> Check the status of your third Economic Impact Payment or “plus-up”
> payment with Get My Payment.
>
> Do not call the IRS as our phone assistors don’t have information
> beyond what is available on IRS.gov.
>
> For more information, see  the Questions and Answers about the Third
> Economic Payment.
>
> We are mailing IRS Notice 1444-C to people who received a third
> Economic Impact Payment. Keep this letter with your tax year 2021
> records.

If your child was born in late 2020 and appears for the first time on your 2020 tax form, then check the status of the plus-up payment via the [get my payment tool](https://www.irs.gov/coronavirus/get-my-payment).

If your child was born in 2021, you will have to wait until you file your tax forms for 2021 in early 2022.